# xCode Source control options disabled

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode5, xcode6

I'm trying to add to svn an existing xCode project. the problem is that all the options under the "Source control" menu are all disabled, the only option I have is "Check out", as shown in the below image

[image]

I have this problem since the upgrade to xCode 6, in the previuos version I was able to add to a repo a project through this menu.

Does anyone have an idea about what is going on?

PS: I know everything can be done by command line, but I think it is a little bit tricky, a visual approach is simplier and better, especially for more delicated tasks and especially in 2014 :)

Comment: under Xcode preferences, there's a "Source Control" tab.  Which checkboxes are enabled?

Comment: source control is enabled and the repo is configured

Comment: It is probably related to the .xccheckout file (See this similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033348/xcode-6-crashes-on-source-control)