# XCode 6 Crashes on Source Control

Tags: xcode6

I am getting very frequent crashes on XCode 6.01 especially when ever I try go to Source Control. I am using SVN.

Is there a workaround I could use ? Is this a known issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably related to the .xccheckout file.

If the project is a xcworkspace, it is located in the xcshareddata folder inside the xcworkspace bundle.

If the project is a xcodeproj, it is located in the project.xcworkspace folder in the xcodeproj bundle.

(The following trick seems to have fixed it for me:

- quit Xcode
- locate the .xccheckout file
- revert this file to what is was when last saved with Xcode 5
- reopen the Xcode project. If Xcode prompts for checking out the project from svn, do not press the ignore or cancel button, instead press the next button. In my case, it checked out another copy of my project from svn and the crash does not occur anymore.)

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Open terminal
Step 2: `cd` to your project's home directory
Step 3: Use commands below

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html