# Xcode 6 Hangs up when code updated from SVN Repository

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Whenever I update or pull the latest code from an SVN repository in Xcode 6, Xcode hangs.

I tried the solution mentioned here without success:
[XCode 6 Crashes on Source Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033348/xcode-6-crashes-on-source-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're seeing Xcode SPOD, take a spindump focused on Xcode and look at the first thread as it will likely give some insight into the spin.  SPODs just occur because the application's main thread (UI thread) is not entering its idle state frequently enough to respond to user input.  I suspect that this is an Xcode bug (blocking the main thread on svn I/O) and you might just need to be patient, but please do file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com and include a sysdiagnose (run 'sudo sysdiagnose Xcode' from Terminal while the issue is reproducing).